# UIWebView taking lots of memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, automatic-ref-counting

In my app when i load `UIWebView` with any Website url the memory jumps from 30mb to around 140mb.
I am using ARC

[image: here is the image for the same] 

and when dismissing the `UIWebViewController`[`Viewcontroller` which contains UIWebView], it doesnt releases the memory.
Can any body help me how to solve this memory issues as well as please also provide  me pointers of memory bestpractices in `ARC`

For loading the webpage :-

```
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:self.url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
```

FOr Dismissing the Viewcontroller:-

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    webview.delegate=nil;
    webview=nil;
}];
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Can you please post some code of how you load the URL.  Also some code where you dismiss the view.  It would be helpful to troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: @BlackFrog sorry for late reply - I have added the code for dismissing the viewcontroller & for loading

Comment: @DAMM108 please use profiler and instruments with iOS device connected to your x-code, don't use them with simulators...

Comment: I have a simple text page and it is using about 35mb of memory =(

Comment: @testing no are you having same issues ?

Comment: @DAMM108: I'm also using a `UIWebView` and the app gets killed when I try to load a big file. Currently, I'm searching for the reason why. My app also jumps from 70 to 200+ MB. On dismiss of a smaller file the used memory stays high. But the problem can also be with my other code not only the `UIWebView` ...

Comment: @DAMM108 my app goes up to 600+ MB. have you solve this?

Comment: Not yet, It is a problem for lots of people . Let us know if some body knows the best practices for UIWebView

Answer (score 6):

wow， today we also meet this problem. when we try to load a web page which contain lots pictures or a huge web page, it's easy to crash. we also find the memory used nearly 200M.

finally we find that we could remove the memory cache of web view

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

you can try it when you receive memory warning. or you can call it in the dealloc method.

if it still have some problems, try to limit the memory cache size by call

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:size]
```

good luck!

Comment: Do i need to set memory cache on the viewcontroller in which webview is loaded or application delegate will do work ?

Comment: actually we set a small memory capacity size for old devices(like iPhone4), i don't know whether it's a necessary to do it. Have you call [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses]; to release web cache when receive memory warning, i guess it could works after you do that.

Comment: As far as I know default memory capacity of [NSURLCache sharedURLCache] is only 20 Mb.

Answer (score 3):

Don't listen to them,

Its not a problem, phones can handle all that memory usage, try using an MKMapView and watch your memory usage soar.

In your simulator, try putting through a low memory warning `cmd+shift+m`, and see what happens, you can't expect all web views to run at the same memory usage, also, you have give a chance for your phone to buffer it all out.

iPhones can handle all of that, so you shouldn't worry much about it.

But try this anyway:

The behaviour of UIWebViews changes if you uncheck "Detects Links" in the nib file, so try toggling that and see what happens.

Comment: this didn't work for me and the uiwebview memory issues are real and severe

Comment: They are real and severe, but are designed to handle the load, and manage the usage when required

Comment: The memory usage is just too high and often causes crashes for all apps running over UIWebView. It's a real problem!

Answer (score 2):

- Use Instruments Allocation tab to see the number of instances of your `UIWebViewController` live in memory. (Cmd + I in Xcode, let Instruments open, select Allocations, and type UIWebViewController in the search bar)
- If there's more than what you expect it to be, lookout for a retain cycle.
- Try to use weak references within blocks instead of self.
- Make sure you aren't holding a strong reference to the `UIWebViewController` object at
  more than one place.
- Put a breakpoint/NSLog in the dealloc method your viewController to see if it is being called.

Comment: Yes, you can implement the method even with ARC, just that you can't call `[super dealloc]`. Also I meant put a log in the dealloc implementation of your viewcontroller.

Comment: tried this -(void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Deaalloc");
    
    
} but it didnt call dealloc method

Comment: Is it being called? If no, I'd suggest you try using instruments to see if the webview is live even after dealloc is called.

Comment: Not dealloc is not called

Comment: Are you storing a reference of the view controller somewhere? Are you using blocks anywhere in your code?

Comment: For dismissing the viewcontroller i am using block does that effects?

Comment: Hmm, don't see anything here. Not sure why the object isn't being dealloced.

Comment: here is the link of mhy viewcontroller https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3b4b7y3b33ywt2/WebViewController.m

Comment: ohk :( ,should i nil the Webviecontroller object in PreviousVIewcontroller from where i am presenting the Webviewcontroller,?

Comment: You could try that as well. Another thing you could try is to remove the HUD temporarily, and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: Ohk, can you tell me some pointers for best practices in ARC- & does dealloc works in arc ? if yes then why it is not calling in my Vewcontroller :(

Comment: removing HUD doesnt helped :(

Comment: What's with all the sad faces. Enjoy programming :)

Comment: @troop231 yeah i do but this time not :P

Comment: @DAMM108 I've written the best practices in the answer

Comment: ok Thanks raunak , I have checked in Instrument & the WebviewCOntroller is deallocated Please see my Intruments screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/moe64kmmyijjwu9/Screen%20Shot.png.

Comment: Why all anonymous VM is taking this much memory , DO i need to worry because of this ?

Comment: Are you using PhoneGap (or equivalent, like appacellerator) or loading a UIWebview with a lot of Javascript code/image, animations?  They do tend to have a significant memory footprint. You should try to load google.com, but keeping the same params when presenting your view controller. If the memory does not go through the roof, then you were probably loading a page requiring too much resources(which I suspect is the culprit). If not, then you might be keeping a strong reference on a memory area of the previous view. In that case, try to give a copy of the parameters passed to your UIWebview.

Comment: @DAMM108 Hey, did you ever get this solved? I've got the same problem.

Comment: @Owatch Are you sure the memory crash is becoz of web view ?, I removed UIWebview as strong property and created a temp IBoutlet variable and to me this worked, Let me know if I can help you in any way

Comment: Well, I've got it as a weak property. And it's just added programmatically via `addSubiew:`. I can't seem to release the memory. I've posted a question about it in fact: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598098/uiwebview-is-not-deallocating-memory

Answer (score 2):

There is no sense to search for a problem until you are sure that problem exists.

There are two possibilities why memory usage is so high:

1.UIWebView is not deallocated.

2.It is some system caching or some specific iOS memory processing algorithm.

In second case you can do nothing. To check first case you can try to use instruments or just subclass UIWebView and add logging to dealloc method.

```
@implementation MyUIWebView

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"MyUIWebView deallocated!");
}

@end
```

Do not forget to change UIWebView to MyUIWebView in your code.

And only if you will be sure that UIWebView is not deallocated you should start to search for strong pointers, retain circles and so on.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
if (webView.isLoading){
    webView.stopLoading;
}
webView.delegate=nil;
```

before this line

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion...]
```

nil ing your webView should be taken care of by ARC. Don't refer to the web view in the completion block.

Comment: it stopsloading & it solves one problem[earlier even coming back to viecontroller, memory was still going up but now its not happening] but still  on coming back to another viewcontroller it is still in the memory & no decrease in memory usage :(

Comment: will need more code or probably the whole project on Github if you need more help. Hard to understand where the problem lies, without knowing the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to remove the UIWebView from the view hierarchy. This would cause an extra retain count and prevent the memory from being reclaimed when you nil'd out the property.

Comment: following is the code which i am doing for removing

Comment: if (viewSourceWebView.isLoading){
        [viewSourceWebView stopLoading];
    }

[viewSourceWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
viewSourceWebView.delegate=nil;
[viewSourceWebView removeFromSuperview];

Comment: most probably the web view is not getting released. i.e. there must be a retain cycle

Answer (score 1):

Just some things you should check:

- A controller has a `strong` reference to its `view`, and this view retains all the subviews as long as you keep them inside the view hierarchy, so any additional properties should be `weak`, including your `webView` property.
- When using ARC there's no need to "`nil`" everything. ARC will `nil` all its `strong` references at `dealloc` automatically.
- No need to do anything with `weak` references neither. Moreover on iOS 5+ `weak` references become `nil` automatically if the referenced object gets deallocated somewhere else.

I think that most likely your whole view controller is getting retained somewhere, and thus its `view` and the `webView`.

Make sure the you only keep `weak` references to the controller and let it be retained by a container or presenting controller so it gets released automatically as long as it gets popped or dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem in my application. I would recommend that you should use WKWebView. WKWebView was introduced with iOS 8. 
You can read more about it here
[apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview)

The memory issue is definitely solved. You will get all the functionality from webview and some more(i.e. progress). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the memory usage of UIWerview immediately, you can try:

1.

```
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

or

2.

```
[webview loadHTMLString: @"" baseURL: nil];
```

or

3.

```
[webview loadData:nil MIMEType:nil textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

It worked to me.