# How to get AVPlayer in web page using WKWebView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avaudioplayer, wkwebview

I used the [youtube-ios-player-hepler](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) library, but there were some memory leaks because `YTPlayerView` inherited `UIWebView`.

[UIWebView is not deallocating memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598098/uiwebview-is-not-deallocating-memory)

Getting the instance of `AVPlayer` with an `UIWebView` which I used to use enabled me control its volume of the sound.

But, as you can see, I could not use it as It had the bugs that `UIWebView` itself has errors of memory leak on iOS9.

That is why I decided to replace the library (`YTPlayer+UIWebView`) into `WKWebView`,
but using `WKWebView` caused another problem that the notification of `AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification` could not be called.

In what kind of way, could you tell me how I can control the volume of sound even with `WKWebView`.

How can you control the volume with `WKWebView`?

Comment: can you get this Avplyer form WKWebView ? if you get please help me